# sinon.restore() doesn't appear to restore the stub method to it's original state

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

I'm trying to call sinon.restore() inside after() hook but it executes nothing which is written inside before() hook.

I've written some code for creating a stub in before() for one of services and trying to return multiple yields.

then, to restore the stub, I'm trying to create sinon.restore() inside after() function but that doesn't execute any of the code written inside before().

TestController1.test.js

```
var sinon = require('sinon');

describe('some test controller 1', function () {

    before(function () {
        var prop12 = { TEST: 'TEST_NAME'};
        testStub1 = sinon.stub(mockService, 'getServiceByName');

        testStub1.onCall(0).yields(null, prop12); // call 0
        testStub1.onCall(1).yields(null, prop12); // call 1
    });

    after(function () {
        sinon.restore();
    });

    it('should test function 0', function() {
        // rely on call 0 and test;
    });

    it('should test function 0', function() {
        // rely on call 1 and test;
    });

});
```

If i don't write sinon.restore() inside after() hook, it executes but there are some other test controllers which have similar stub on the same service so they fail too.

Thanks in advance...